# The method in the type is not applicable for the arguments (even though they are?!)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to call a method using parameters that definitely match my args, yet I get this error...

> The method getAdministratablePaging(Long, ContentFilter, int, int, Integer, Integer) in the type ContentService is not applicable for the arguments (Long, ContentFilter, int, int, Integer, Integer)

The code is...

```
ResultPage knowledgeCenters = _kcs.getAdministratablePaging(ContentConstants.KNOWLEDGE_ROOT, filter, 0, Constants.COUNT_ALL, ContentConstants.COLUMN_SIZE, Constants.SORT_ORDER_ASCENDING);
```

I'm working in Eclipse and have tried Clean and rebooting the IDE. Suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Do you happen to have two different `ContentFilter` classes in your project?

Comment: If you pass one when the method expects the other, yes.

Comment: @nscoppin Yes, potentially. The method signature may expect `com.packageA.ContentFilter` but be receiving `com.packageB.ContentFilter`

Comment: @Kon You solved it! I was importing the wrong ContentFilter object. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting my comment as an answer in case it can help somebody seeing this question in the future.

When you see a message like this, then the only possibility is that there are multiple types of one of the parameter objects. In this case, @nscoppin had two different definitions for `ContentFilter`. Either import the correct one, or use the fully qualified name in the method call, ie

```
someMethod(com.packageA.subPackage.ContentFilter);
```